# Create deferred enumerable from Func<IEnumerable<T>>

Tags: c#, linq, enumerable

Is there a built-in/standard way of creating a deferred `IEnumerable<T>`, given a `Func<IEnumerable<T>>`? My Google skills may be weak...

Suppose I know that some method `Foo` that returns an `IEnumerable<T>` executes immediately (and is perhaps long-running). I want to pass it into method `Bar` that takes in an `IEnumerable<T>` but I don't want `Foo` to be execute its long-running process to return items until `Bar` starts iterating over the items:

```
IEnumerable<string> Foo()
{
    var items = GetItems(); // long running process
    return items;
}

void Bar(IEnumerable<string> foo)
{
     /* something else long-running, or return immediately if some pre-condition fails and we don't even want to iterate over foo */
    foreach (var item in foo)
    {
        // do something
    }
}   

void Run()
{
    IEnumerable<string> foo = GetFooWrapper(Foo)
    Bar(items);
}

IEnumerable<string> GetFooWrapper(Func<IEnumerable<string>> foo)
{
    // ???
}
```

What's the best way of implementing `GetFooWrapper`? My simplest approach was the following, but if there's some "better" way of doing it, I'd like to know about it. Not that it matters, but R# suggests simplifying it to `return foo();`.

```
IEnumerable<string> GetFooWrapper(Func<IEnumerable<string>> foo)
{
    foreach (var item in foo())
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess if you _really_ didn't want to write the wrapper yourself, you could do something like `Bar(new Func<IEnumerable<string>>[] { () => Foo(items) }, x => x());`. But what's wrong with the wrapper? Do you have a _specific_ problem you are trying to solve? If you just want someone to look over your code, you should post on codereview.stackexchange.com instead (being sure to comply with their posting requirements/standards, of course).

Comment: Do you have a control over re-designing the `GetItems`? If so, I can suggest and alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for the [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) class. It defers the creation of an object until it is first used.

Here's an example that would defer execution of the `Foo` method until the `Value` property is accessed for the first time. Once `Foo` is executed once, it will not be executed again unless a new `Lazy<T>` is created.

```
var items = new Lazy<IEnumerable<string>>(Foo);
foreach(var item in items.Value) // delay starts here
{
    // do work
}
```